# .htaccess bulk redirect if contains string to new path

Tags: string, .htaccess, contains, bulk

old Site urls is like

`https://example.com/en/products/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=productdetails&virtuemart_product_id=3934&virtuemart_category_id=275&Itemid=142`

and i want to redirect to a new category path

`https://example.com/shop/en/14-presentation-scanners`

like
old category

- `virtuemart_category_id=275` new category is `14-presentation-scanners`
- `virtuemart_category_id=276` new category is `15-handheld-scanners`

i tried

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)virtuemart_category_id=275(.*)$ https://example.com/shop/en/14-presentation-scanners [L,R=301]
```

And

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} virtuemart_category_id=275
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com/shop/en/14-presentation-scanners/? [L,R=301]
```

but not working, any suggestions?

Comment: Try `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} virtuemart_category_id=275`

Comment: You need to understand that those request arguments ("virtuemart_category_id=275") are NOT part of the URL, but of the "query string". That means you cannot caputure them from the `REQUEST_URI`, but only from `QUERY_STRING`. That is clearly documented, actually: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond